# Pig ReadTimeOut Exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I've installed hortonworks sandbox on Virtual Box. (6092MB of Ram)
I'm following [this tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_9).

When I try to execute one simple script

[image: Script Image]

Using arguments: -useHCatalog

Execute on Tez.

I got this error:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your post and include a specific question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like HiveServer is not running.  Can you open Ambari (browser - port 8080) and verify that it is running?  Ambari can let you restart Hive if it is not.